# How to add labels to nodes in a CIRCULAR GRAPH with networkx in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, label

I'm drawing a circular graph using the method:

```
nx.draw_circular(G, node_color='b', edge_color='#909090', node_size=500)
```

Basically what I want to do is to add labels to the nodes but I don't find the way to add them in this type of graphs. I tried using:

`nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,labels=labels,pos=nx.spring_layout(G),font_size=16)`

but there is a problem with the position layout, it is not next/in each node.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(20))
e = [(0,1),(0,2)]
G.add_edges_from(e)

# some labels
labels={}

nx.draw_circular(G, node_color='y', edge_color='#909090', node_size=500,labels=labels)

plt.axis('equal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `draw_networkx_labels()` function with pos from `nx.circular_layout()`:

```
G = nx.Graph()
e = [(0, 1), (0, 2)]
G.add_edges_from(e)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_circular(G, node_color='#2ea28a', node_size=1000)

plt.show()
```